# Override Zone Rendering

Tags: orchardcms

I'm trying to override the rendering of the actual zone template.

It renders something like this:

```
<div class="zone zone-hero" shape-id="13">      

    <div class="inner" shape-id="14">
        content is stuffed in here
    </div>

</div>
```

I found that if I put Zone.cshtml into the root of my template, I can override it's rendering.  What I can't figure out is how to get it to render its widgets and content if it exists.  I tried using @Display(Model.Content), but had no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is enumerate the shapes that it has under itself and call Display on each of them. Casting to IEnumerable should do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

This template respects the shape's Attribute and Classes properties and sets the Id field according to Orchard's conventions. So, for the developer a template with this code behaves quite as expected.

```
@{
    Model.Id = string.Concat("zone-", Model.Hint.ToLowerInvariant());
    var tag = Tag(Model, "section");
}
@tag.StartElement
@DisplayChildren(Model)
@tag.EndElement
```

If you want to override for example the Content zone, create a page named `zone-content.cshtml` in the Views folder of your theme project and copy the code above into it.

Comment: Plus one for explaining how to override the template for a specific zone.

Comment: There is no need to manually set `Model.Id` (and it throws and error if `Model.Hint` is not set.) If you simply remove that line and replace "section" by "div" you will get the _exact_ same result as the default Zone shape in `Orchard.Core.Shapes.CoreShapes`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as Bertrand suggested (which gives you more control on rendering each element in the zone), or do `@DisplayChildren(Model)`.